# WebStorm 2018.3: Unable to write template literal since update

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Since updating to `WebStorm 2018.3` I'm unable to write template literals.
As you might see in the animated image below, I can write the first `` ` ``, but as soon as I hit the key combination again, the character is replaced by the new one. Hitting `spacebar` doesn't work anymore either.

Any suggestions?

[image: Bug explaining by gif]

Comment: What OS is it, what keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @lena I'm on macOS 10.14.1 (18B75) using german keyboard layout

Comment: For what it's worth, I have IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3, macOS 10.14.1, German keyboard, and cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: From my side for what it's worth, CTRL + ALT + S (Settings) has a good search option. Note that WebStorm has settings for specific languages (Javascript, Typescript ... ).

Comment: I've set my `Keymap` to default, nothing changed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue is tracked as [IDEA-189203](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189203), please follow it for updates